# RadAutoCompleteTextView fires @tokenRemoved when navigating away from page

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript, token, nativescript-vue

Inside @tokenRemoved i have an api call for removing users, and would be quite bad removing them when I'm not pressing the X button. Is there a way to avoid it? Tried using @tokenSelected, but then again you need to select the token first and then press the X, and if someone missclicked, they wouldn't notice the mistake before later on.

```
 <RadAutoCompleteTextView ref="autocomplete"
                          :items="dataItems"
                          @didAutoComplete="autoFillIn"
                          @loaded="onLoaded"
                          @tokenRemoved="autoRemove"
>
<SuggestionView ~suggestionView suggestionViewHeight="200" v-if="hideAssignedTo">
  <StackLayout v-suggestionItemTemplate orientation="vertical" padding="30" class="h3">
      <v-template>
        <StackLayout>
          <Label class="h3 m-10" :text="item.text"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </v-template>
   </StackLayout>
 </SuggestionView>
</RadAutoCompleteTextView>

<script>
export default: {
        methods: {
            autoRemove({token}) {
                axios.put('Tasks', {
                    TaskId: this.$store.state.fooModule.task.Id,
                    RemoveUser: token.text
                }).then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                }).catch(e => console.log(e))
            }
        }
}
```

This is the code that I have for removing the token.

Comment: You mean while closing the page or navigation back to the page where rad auto complete is present?

Comment: Closing the page, closing the app and reopens it and this.$navigateTo with clearHistory: true, fires the tokenRemoved.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue, please share a Playground sample. Between, may I know what you are exactly doing inside loaded event, the event is triggered when the component is loaded (navigating to the page, upon application resume etc.,) If you are doing any data manipulation there, it's possible the token removed event is triggered due to that.